# How to find the limit of functions at $x=0$ when drawing graphs?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, graphing-functions, limits-without-lhopital

For example, sketch $y=x(\ln x)^2$.

What is not immediately obvious is the limit of $y$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right.

The same goes for $y=x^x$.

Is there a way, in general, to find out the behavior of such curves as $x$ approaches zero?

Comment: How about computing the limit analytically? In addition, for the sake of plotting the graph, you can investigate function and its derivatives, check whether there are asymptotes, etc. For example, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mv6Yb8fHlFg).

Comment: Generally....one uses lhopital's :)

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:*

Re-write $x$ln$(x)^2$ as $\frac{x}{\frac{1}{lnx^2}}$ and apply L'Hopital's Rule.

Re-write $x^x$ as $e^{xln(x)}$ and solve.

Alternatively, you could do as you said (graph y= the expressions with a graphing calculator), and find the y value as x approaches 0 for both problems.

Comment: The question has the limits without L'Hopital's, which is why I put the comment I did

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the limit $$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(t)}{t}=0$$ rerwrite $x(\ln(x))^2$ as $(\sqrt{x}\ln(x))^2$ and then $\left(-2\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)^2$. Now take $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Note that the function $x\to x^2$ is continious on $\mathbb{R}$ and since $x\to 0^+$ so we have $t\to+\infty$.